# How do I make Tkinter entry focusout validation happen more than just the first time?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have an application that, for a part of it, will take a user's input and format it into a standardized time format. To do this, i have a `time` input that has a `focusout` event tied to it that calls the time parser/replacer method. However, while testing it and just setting a message label to output some stuff, i noticed that it only triggers once...

Below is some sample code to show the problem.

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

message_var = StringVar()
message = Label(root, textvariable=message_var, height=2, width=35, bg="light grey")
time_var = StringVar()
time = Entry(root, textvariable=time_var, validate="focusout", validatecommand=time_update)
lose_focus_var = StringVar()
lose_focus_textbox = Entry(root, textvariable=lose_focus_var)

message_var.set("Enter a time below.")
lose_focus_var.set("Click here to lose focus.")

def time_update():
    """
    Updates the time field to show standardized times.
    """
    cur_entry = time_var.get()
    if len(cur_entry) == 0:
        message_var.set("0!")
    elif len(cur_entry) == 1:
        message_var.set("1!")
    elif len(cur_entry) == 2:
       message_var.set("2!")
    elif len(cur_entry) == 3:
       message_var.set("3!")
    elif len(cur_entry) == 4:
       message_var.set("4!")
    elif len(cur_entry) == 5:
       message_var.set("5!")
    else:
       message_var.set("TOO MANY!")
       time_var.set("")

message.pack()
time.pack()
lose_focus_textbox.pack()
```

To reproduce my issue, run the code above. In the window that appears, click into the blank textbox, enter any number of characters, then click into the textbox that says "Click here to lose focus." You'll see that the message widget updates correctly! Yay!

However, if you click into the first textbox again, change the number of characters, then click the Lose Focus box again, the message will not update again. You will need to kill the window and re-run the code for the messages widget to update again.

If i add the `time_update` call to the other textbox (and refactor `time_update` to figure out which textbox called it), the message update will happen once for each text box. But only once.

Is there a way for me to re-trigger the `<FocusOut>` event, other than destroying the Entry widget and recreating it? Why doesn't it trigger every time?

Comment: Just a quick update, i thought maybe it was because i was using the `validatecommand` feature and wasn't returning True or False. Editing the code to include `return True` or `return False` in the `time_update` function did not change the issue described.

Comment: As posted, your code doesn't run. You use `time_update` before you define it, and you never call mainloop. It really helps us write answers if you give us actual working code.

Comment: Code works as written through simple copy/paste into my Python interpreter... i suppose i should have specified that.

Comment: You should always try to run it by putting it in a file and running it from the command line. What's happening is that your interpreter already has some things defined in it that this code depends on. Since we can't run your interpreter, we require code that runs in a new interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem, as you mention in a comment to your own question, is that you're not returning True or False. The whole point of the validation is to let tkinter know if it should allow the edit or not, and it does this based on the return value.

Beyond that, however, the main problem is that you're changing the value of the widget within the validation function. When you do that, tkinter will automatically disable the validation. There are workarounds, but you really shouldn't be changing the value in the validation function. If I were a user, I would find this behavior to be extremely frustrating.

If you want to change the value when it loses focus, consider adding a binding to `<FocusOut>` rather than using the validation functions.

Comment: Man, i don't know why i thought it would be a better idea to use a validation function than a binding. I had no idea validation is disabled when a value is set, though—thanks for the insight!

Comment: Since the time formatting is only updated to verify for the user that the time they intended was entered, i promise it won't be frustrating. :D

Comment: @Staunch: if a user types a string of digits that is too long and you erase them all, it will definitely be frustrating. Simply disallow the character that makes it too long -- that's how validation is supposed to work. Don't throw away data entered by the user.